# Is it possible to extend(heritance) class in Objective-c as is traditionally conceptualised in other languages?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am having a lot of repeated code throughout my app classes given that some properties & method are stable across all my views.

I am looking to extend whatever class I am working with so that it automatically `inherit` all `properties and methods` that I think should be common to those classes.

I looked into the [apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1) on extending classes. But I am left confused in the terms of the level of heritance that I can achieve.

I've successfully created `Categories` on lets say a `UIViewController`. But that limits me to only be able to declare `Methods`. I can not declare `Properties` on my `Category` and call them in side my `Category` or in the Extended Class. I want to be able to declare `Properties` and use it inside and outside my Extended-Class.

Its my first time trying to extend a class in objective-c taking full advantage of heritance but I do not know if it is possible. Am I missing something?

As an example in the code below every time I try to instantiate `activityIndicatorView` inside my method `_activityIndicator` it wouldn't recognise it. I've tried `@syntetize` and `@dynamic` but it doesn't work

**NOTE:** I am seeking an answer based on how to achieve heritance of methods and propeties. not highlighting what categories cant do (as I already tried and know I cant have properties there)

My attempt went as far of

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (customViewController1)

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *activityIndicatorView;
- (void) _activityIndicator;
@end

#import "UIViewController+customViewController1.h"

@implementation UIViewController (customViewController1)


- (void) _activityIndicator {
//......
}
```

Comment: Class extension and inheritance are two different pair of shoes. With an extension you extend an existing class but do not create a new subclass. Extensions (categories) work for additional methods, not for properties. If you need to extend it with poperties then it gets a bit tricky.

Comment: Why don't you just inehrit? Plus the regular inheritance all of your classes could implment (conform to) the same protocol. A protocol is similar to an inteface in Java. With a protocol, too, you can add mehtods only and not properties (afaik) but you could of course add the getters and setters you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Categories are a nice way to add functionality while at the same time conforming to an object oriented principle to prefer composition over inheritance.
Categories only add methods, you can't add variables to a class using categories. If the class needs more properties, then it has to be subclassed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad, plus it is not clear what your problem is. Yes, you can subclass in Objective-C.

This is all very well documented in Apple's document "Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C", section "[The Object Model](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Articles/ooObjectModel.html)", subsection "[Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Articles/ooObjectModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005149-CH5-SW12)".

Answer (score 0):

When *you* use the term “extend”, you're talking about creating a subclass. This is, IIRC, how the term is used in Java and some other languages.

Apple uses the term differently (as Hermann Klecker hinted in his first comment). They literally mean extending an *existing* class with more functionality (in the form of methods)—that's what categories do. This is the normal English definition; extending something in the real world generally does not create a new thing.

Objective-C supports subclasses, too; it just doesn't call them “extending” the superclass. It's called creating a subclass, which inherits from the superclass.

Answer (score -1):

Strctly spoken you cannot add a property to an existing class any differnt than creating a subclass.

If you cannot halp yourself and subclassing is not an option, then you can extend the class with getters and setters for the property that you want to store within the class. 
Instead of really storing it as a member/instance variable/property, which you can't do, you could store the object (it cannto be a scalar, must be an object) in the global space using `objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy)`.

This is some sort of global dictionary with two keys, the key itself and the ojbect to which you want to associat the stored object to. In your case that is the object of the type of the exended class. The setter stores it there and the getter receives it from there using `objc_getAssociatedObject`.

You delete an association by sending `nil` as `value` to `objc_setAssociatedObject`

AFAIK retained associated objects (values) are released shortly after the object that holds the associateion (object) is deallocated.

For further details see the Ojbective-C Runtime Reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Just: I do not say that this is strictly following the OO paradigm. :-)